# snort-mysql not starting on Ubuntu server

Tags: snort

I am following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SnortIDS

I've set up the database, everything has installed correctly, and I've configured the snort.conf file so it outputs to a database (with creds all filled out ok).

When I run /etc/init.d/snort start, it fails but does not produce any error message other than [fail].

The last few lines of /var/log/syslog are:

```
snort[5687]: database: must enter database name in configuration file#012
snort[5687]: FATAL ERROR:
```

My output database line in the snort.conf file is:

```
output database: log, mysql, user=snort password=... dbname=snort host=localhost
```

I have tried it with the commas separating everything, putting quotes around stuff, etc. The password is only made up of letters (after I thought maybe a number was throwing it off).

Answer (score 0):

> **[parameter list]**
>
> The parameter list consists of key value pairs (See Table 4). The
>   syntax of the parameter list is a series of `key=value` pairs each
>   separated by a space.
>
> The only parameter that is absolutely necessary is `dbname`. All other
>   parameters are optional but may be necessary depending on the RDBMS
>   configuration.

Move `dbname` to be the first parameter to see what happens:

```
output database: log, mysql, dbname=snort user=snort host=localhost password=...
```

Comment: Nope, rearranging the line results in the same error.

Answer (score -1):

In your snort.conf comment the line:

```
include dabases.conf
```